# MySQL/PHP syntax error - looks fine to me

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I am doing a fulltext search query in my script and was having trouble.  So I added a quick "echo mysql_error" because I was getting false results when I shouldn't have been.  Here is the actual typed query:

```
(*Sending these args respectively: 'announc_threads', 'subject', 'replying'*)

public function searchFulltext ($table, $field, $against) {
     $query = "SELECT TID, authorUID, timeStarted, 
               WHERE MATCH (".$field.") AGAINST ('$against') AS score
               FROM ".$table."
               WHERE MATCH (".$field.") AGAINST ('$against')";
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE MATCH (subject) AGAINST ('replying') AS score FROM announc_threads WHERE M' at line 1
```

Looking at the error, everything looks just fine. The biggest problem I have with queries is single/double quotes and using variables (it always seems to change what it wants) - but even those look good, single quotes around the strings, no quotes around table/field names - grrr - do you see anything wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Oh, and yes I double checked that there is a fulltext index for the field I'm searching in the correct table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `where` in the list of fields, in your `select` clause.

I suppose you intend to select the score, and copy-pasted the `match...against` stuff from your `where` clause, and, that, as a consequence, that `where` is probably a copy-paste mistake, and should be removed :

```
$query = "SELECT TID, authorUID, timeStarted, 
           MATCH (".$field.") AGAINST ('$against') AS score
           FROM ".$table."
           WHERE MATCH (".$field.") AGAINST ('$against')";
```

*(The `where` I removed was at the begining of the second line of that portion of code)*